# Bootstrap multiselect onfocus is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the icon color when i focus on a bootstrap multiselect. But onfocus is not working for multiselect. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-7" id="hearDiv">
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users" id="heari"></i>
   </span>
   <select class="form-control" name="hear[]" 
    id="hear" onfocusin="icon(this.id)" onfocusout="iconout(this.id)" 
    multiple>
    <option value="Google Search">Google Search</option>
    <option value="Social Media (Facebook, Instagram etc.)">Social Media 
     (Facebook, Instagram etc.)</option>
    <option value="From a Friend">From a Friend</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function icon(id){
    document.getElementById(id+"i").style.color = ("#ff3333");
}
function iconout(id){
    document.getElementById(id+"i").style.color = ("#595959");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
function icon(id) {
  id.style.color = ("#ff3333");
}

function iconout(id) {
  id.style.color = ("#595959");
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-7" id="hearDiv">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users" id="heari"></i></span>
      <select class="form-control" name="hear[]" id="hear" onfocus="icon(this)" onfocusout="iconout(this)" multiple>
    <option value="Google Search">Google Search</option>
    <option value="Social Media (Facebook, Instagram etc.)">Social Media 
     (Facebook, Instagram etc.)</option>
    <option value="From a Friend">From a Friend</option>
   </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But its changing the option color. Maybe because of the same id. Thats why i passed only id and then changed it.

Comment: If I understand the question right, you want to have a different color while selecting options in the form-group? Correct ? @AradBin